Protobuf net 3.2.30 nuget requires 2 versions of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll i.e. 6.0.0 and 4.5.3. How to ship these libraries or fix?
System.Collections.Immutable
7.0.0
is dependent on
<dependency id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="6.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />

and
System.Memory
4.5.5
is dependent on
<dependency id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" />

How I will be able to ship these properly ?
The the Release folder I am getting 6.0.0 version when shipped on of the application required the 4.5.3 version of the dll. and thows runtime error
ExceptionObject: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
 // Span`1.ctor()
10/01/24 18:43:52.752 00 SystemUI:44304 ERR: File name: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'


What is the actual problem? Your code does not build? Fails in runtime? Can you please provide a [mre]?

is this .NET Framework? Have you added an assembly binding redirect for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe? (all of these problems should go away in modern .NET, i.e. .NET Core or .NET 5+ etc)

Yes @MarcGravell, this is a .Net Framework 4.8 application. My libraries are in netstatndard 2.0. I wanted to understand the versioning issue before adding assembly binding. And also like to know which version of protobuf can be used without assembly binding redirect.

@soumyasambitKunda speaking as a library author: netstandard is just... bad. By all means include it as a fallback for exotic runtime, but in general: multitarget > netstandard

To be clear: the need for assembly binding redirect here isn't really a library thing. There are some severe, well-known problems with the automated tooling for a handful of libraries (unsafe, memory, valuetuple tc) that requires assembly binding redirect to fix on .net framework. This problem has been fixed: the fix is called ".NET Core" (or modern .Net, i.e. .Net 8, .Net 9, etc)
